# sklearn randomforest accuracy

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

for the same training and test datset, the accuracy of KNN is 0.53, for RandomForest and AdaBoost ,the accuracy is 1, can anyone help?

codes:

```
## prepare data
begin_date='20140101'
end_date='20160908'
stock_code='000001'  #平安银行
data=ts.get_hist_data(stock_code,start=begin_date,end=end_date)
close=data.loc[:,'close']
df=data[:-1] 
diff=np.array(close[1:])-np.array(close[:-1])
label=1*(diff>=0)   
df.loc[:,'diff']=diff  
df.loc[:,'label']=label

#split dataset into trainging and test 
df_train=df[df.index<'2016-07-08']
df_test=df[df.index>='2016-07-08']
x_train=df_train[df_train.columns[:-1]]
y_train=df_train['label']
x_test=df_test[df_test.columns[:-1]]
y_test=df_test['label']

##KNN
clf2 = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
clf2.fit(x_train, y_train)
accuracy2 = clf2.score(x_test, y_test)
pred_knn=np.array(clf2.predict(x_test))

#RandomForest
clf3 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,n_jobs=-1)
clf3.fit(x_train, y_train)
accuracy3 = clf3.score(x_test, y_test)
pred_rf=np.array(clf3.predict(x_test))

print  accuracy1,accuracy2,accuracy3
```

Comment: These are different estimators. So, it is not surprising if you get different accuracy scores. Your question is not very clear. Are you worried about accuracy of your randomforest or KNN?  Here is some suggestions that may help you: Please plot the learning curve for all estimators (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html#learning-curves). You may simply overfitting your data. Besides, for the best performance you need to tune the hyperparameters of your models (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html).

Comment: thank MhFarahani !  I figure out that the label is based on one of the features,  i forgot to drop it from the datasets.   your suggestion of plot the learning curve for all estimators  and overfitting is still  helpful for beginner

Answer (score 0):

Different models give different accuracy on same dataset in most of the cases. For example, if you are trying to train and test a dataset with LogisticRegression and SVM, then it is highly likely that both the models will give different score. In order to choose best model for your data, you need to first explore the dataset and then choose some algorithm that performs better in the case.

Also, as your RandomForest and AdaBoost are giving an accuracy of 1, it is very likely that your model is 'overfitted'.